# Правильное создание конкурирующих NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout

Есть 3 объекта `UIView`, размещены они с помощью Auto Layout следующим образом:

[image: Расстановка элементов]

Высота view3 (синий) постоянна, а вот для view1 (красный) и view2 (зелёный) она меняется в зависимости от содержимого (допустим, внутри них есть `UILabel` с динамически изменяемым количеством строк). Требуется, чтобы расстояние между view1 и view3 всегда было больше 20, а расстояние между view2 и view3 было больше 30. Если учесть, что мы не знаем заранее, что будет выше - view1 или view2, то как можно решить данную проблему с помощью Auto Layout? Разрешается использовать код на Swift или Objective-C, но желательно показать всё в пределах storyboard-файла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надеюсь правлиьно понял смысл вопроса.

1. Отношение первой `UIView` ко второй
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отношение которое >= 30 имеет приоритет 1000
Отношение которое `Equals:` 100 имеет приоритет 900

Отношение второй `UIView` к третьей решается таким же способом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Constraint для изменения положения объекта будет с приоритетом 900, но он не опуститься ниже Constraint с приоритетом 1000.

Comment: Я тоже надеюсь, что правильно понял Ваш ответ. Надо создать по 2 NSLayoutConstraint - один будет говорить "расстояние обязательно должно быть больше N", а второй - "хорошо, если оно будет равно N".